# Retrofit's `enqueue()` doesn't re-assign value of object in time for the return statement?

Tags: kotlin, callback, retrofit2

I'm making a call to the API and the response body is assigned to an object inside Retrofit's `enqueue()`, the problem is that enqueue finishes too quickly for the value to be assigned before the return statement of the function body is called.

Previously, I was using `MutableLiveData` before and it took care of that because it's always observing the data and when it changes it assigns it with no problem but now I don't want to use any MutableLiveData or Observables because I'm trying to prepare the data before any UI is actually drawn on the screen.

```
fun getResponse(
        weatherLocationCoordinates: WeatherLocation
    ): RequestResponse {
        weatherApiService.getCurrentWeather(
            weatherLocationCoordinates.latitude,
            weatherLocationCoordinates.longitude

        ).enqueue(object : Callback<WeatherResponse> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<WeatherResponse>,
                    response: Response<WeatherResponse>
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        // This where I do the assigning 
                        requestResponse = RequestResponse(response.body(), true)
                    }
                }
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<WeatherResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    requestResponse = RequestResponse(null, false)
                }
            })
        // When this is called, enqueue is still not finished 
        // therefore I get the wrong value, I get the previously set initialization value of the obj.
        return requestResponse
```

}

Should I be using Callbacks or something else? I'm not sure on how to implement the callback.

Comment: That's just how asynchronous calls work. Like you said, either implement something with callbacks, or an observable pattern like live data or rx streams.

Comment: @Fred callbacks will not make it noticeably "slower"?

Comment: I don't see why. Unless they're wrongly implemented

Comment: @Fred Is it possible to get an example of some sort?

Comment: oh yeah sure, I just thought you were aware of how to do it since you mentioned it. Sorry, I'll post an answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on the comments here's an approach with callbacks:

Let's suppose we change the method signature to:

```
fun getResponse(
    weatherLocationCoordinates: WeatherLocation,
    onSuccess: (WeatherResponse) -> Unit = {},
    onError: (Throwable) -> Unit = {}
) {
    weatherApiService.getCurrentWeather(
        weatherLocationCoordinates.latitude,
        weatherLocationCoordinates.longitude

    ).enqueue(object : Callback<WeatherResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(
             call: Call<WeatherResponse>,
            response: Response<WeatherResponse>
        ) {
           if (response.isSuccessful) {
              onSuccess(response.body())
           } else {
              onError(CustomHttpExceptionWithErrorDescription(response))
           }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<WeatherResponse>, t: Throwable) {
           onError(t)
        }
    })
}
```

*`CustomHttpExceptionWithErrorDescription` will have to be something you code that can simply parse the error gotten from the server. Anything that is not 2XX status code*

This method accepts 2 extra parameters - one gets called upon success the other on error. The idea is to call it like:

```
getResponse(
   weatherLocationCoordinates,
   onSuccess = {
       // do something with response
   },
   onError = {
       // do something with the error
   }
)
```

Because they have default parameters you actually don't need to specify both callbacks. Just the one you are interested in. Examples:

```
// react only to successes
getResponse(
   weatherLocationCoordinates,
   onSuccess = {
       // do something with response
   }
)

// react only to errors
getResponse(weatherLocationCoordinates) {
   // do something with the error
}

// just call the network calls and don't care about success or error
getResponse(weatherLocationCoordinates)
```